# "Error: unbound variable or constructor: False"

Tags: list, function, sml

I am testing if a list is a palindrome, so I made a function called `reverse` which reverses a list, and a function called `palindrome` that uses pattern matching to try to see if the list matches the reversed list. But I'm getting `unbound variable or constructor` errors.

```ml
(*  This function returns true for all patterns that match itself in reverse as well as for the empty list
Otherwise _ wildcard character we return False  *)

fun palindrome (xs): bool =
  let val  rev = reverse(xs) 
  in
    case xs of 
      rev => True
      | [] => True
      | _ => False
  end;
```

Output:

```
Error: unbound variable or constructor: False
vaje1.sml:125.10-125.14 Error: unbound variable or constructor: True
vaje1.sml:123.9-123.13 Error: unbound variable or constructor: True
```

Comment: The booleans are spelled "true" and "false". No capital letters. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: As a side note, a shorter version is `fun palindrome xs = reverse xs = xs`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides calling the constants `true` and `false` what they're properly called, another mistake lies in how to compare two lists for equality. As molbdnilo points out, the simplest way to do this is `one = other`, i.e. (using the built-in `List.rev` function):

```ml
fun palindrome xs =
  xs = List.rev xs
```

This works because, if you have a value that is comparable for equality, a list of those values is automatically comparable for equality. If this weren't the case, you could define such a function recursively in the following way:

```ml
fun list_eq ([], []) = true
  | list_eq (x::xs, y::ys) = (x = y) andalso list_eq (xs, ys)
  | list_eq (_, _) = false (* lists of mismatching length *)

(* one way *)
fun palindrome xs =
  list_eq (xs, List.rev xs)
```

But the built-in `=` already does this.

The way you're using *case-of* appears to be an attempt to compare two variables, `xs` and `rev` (not the function) for equality by using the pattern `rev` in the hope that such a pattern refers to the variable `rev`: It would in Prolog and Erlang, but not in SML. If you must use a *case-of* like this, here is what you could do (again using the built-in `List.rev` function):

```ml
fun palindrome xs =
  case List.rev xs of
    xs' => (xs = xs')
```

although this is just as unnecessary, since `xs'` is only being referred to once.